# What are the benefits to product teams when designs are done in user flows

Tags: workflow, features, product-design, product-management

Recently i've been designing UI for various features in sketch in terms of user flows. This means multiple artboards of each state and scenario will be in a layout of a flow. similar to how Jakub Linowski does it. 
https://player.vimeo.com/video/43869717

Besides individual benefits as a designer like being easier to cover all edge cases and errors. I'm curious how would this view would benefit other members in the product team like product managers and ux researchers in their own processes and work.

e.g. seeing how each feature spans across the whole product and where it overlaps with other products. thus avoiding issues that could occur from overlapping features

e.g. seeing a birds eye view of the user journey of each persona across a product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over the past year we have adopted a similar method to producing specifications for a new app.

Gone are lengthy specifications and use cases and in are wireframes, often backed by workflows or prototypes.

We have found that clients much prefer the visual style. It allows them to clearly see a path and an action. Furthermore, the fear that working like this would balloon project timelines has been quashed as designers can take the low-fi wireframes and produce high-definition wireframes, without reinventing the wheel and in the knowledge the design is pretty much signed-off.

Giving the customer early sight of the design allows for feedback to be assimilated quickly and easily, so it works for managers and the team as a whole.

With regards to an example, I don't as I've just changed jobs, however I found this in my drop box, it's not great as it's not complete, but I think we were in the process of changing the flowchart elements for screens.

[image: Example flow with screens.]

Here's another one, that's waiting to be linked:

[image: Wireframes - pre-link]

Finally found one!

[image: Linked visual workflow]

Comment: Thanks @darryl   could you share some case by case or specific examples how you guys used user flows